# Div with slanted edge that maintains aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create headers with slanted edges that maintain their aspect ratio no matter what height they appear as. Is this possible to accomplish using CSS alone?

This image shows what the headers look like if they're only one line long:

[image]

And if they're two or more lines long, they should appear like:

[image]

The issue I'm running in to is that I can't make the white half triangle overlaying the right portion of the header to resize, let alone resize with its same aspect ratio. Here's what happens on multi lines as-is:

[image]

The code to display the headers right now is:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Public Information</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1>Board Meeting Schedule</h1>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background: #0D3C5B;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 18px 80px 12px 20px;
    position: relative;
}
    header:before {
        border-left: 58px solid transparent;
        border-top: 62px solid #FFF;
        content: "\0020";
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 0;
    }

    header nav {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 6px 0 0;
    }

        header nav ul {
            color: #42AFE3;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 0.75em;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 1.6666666666666666666666666666667em;
            line-height: 2.25em;
            list-style: normal;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

            header nav ul li {
                display: inline-block;
            }

                header nav ul li a {
                    color: #42AFE3;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }

                header nav ul li:after {
                    content: "\003E";
                    padding: 0 4px;
                }

    header h1 {
        color: #FFF;
        float: left;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 1em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    header:after {
        clear: both;
        content: "\0020";
        display: block;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doLuj6me/

Comment: I'd rather settle it by using background image

Comment: I wouldn't, as background images don't scale as nicely. I always prefer to use CSS when possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup! The triangle border trick is *awesome* but unfortunately it's very inflexible when it comes to dynamically sized elements.

Fortunately, CSS3 gave us some new tools to exploit in gamey ways.

Here's what you do:

**CSS**

```
header {
    background: #0D3C5B;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 18px 80px 12px 20px;
    position: relative;
}

header:before {
    content:'';
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

That's the meat of it.  We're putting a pseudo element at the end of the header, twisting it 45º and making it so large that it's going to cover any reasonable size.

## [Fiddle illustrating this bit of hackery](http://jsfiddle.net/doLuj6me/1/)

Voila.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the right triangle to position:absolute; and right:0; bottom:0; You'll need to be responsible for ensuring the text doesn't get covered if it goes long... Also make sure the containing div has overflow:clip set so the right triangle doesn't escape the div :)

Hmmm... I missed that you don't have a separate element for the triangle. You should split the header into a container with a text div and the right triangle div. The container should have position: relative and the right triangle div as I mentioned above.

Comment: You should always avoid adding tags simply for styling if you're interested in maintaining semantically sound HTML, which is important for SEO, accessibility and general readability.  This is why we have pseudo elements which don't pollute the DOM.  Just a tip.

Comment: Fair enough but do you have a better way to achieve what he wants? Avoiding is fine but if it works and semantically sound HTML will not achieve it then this would be an edge case where he would want to do this.

Comment: Yup, check my answer.

Comment: Nice... I don't have as much experience with css3's more exotic features. I am going to dig into this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which doesn't use transforms or rotations:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/twxgnjcw/

Try changing the height of the DIV and you will see that the slanted line grows with the DIV.

```
div {
    height: 400px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: -2000px;
    margin-left: -2000px;
    border-width: 2000px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Christopher was on the right track. All you have to do is to position your `header:before` at the bottom right and give your borders bigger dimensions than you'll need:

```
header:before { 
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 400px solid transparent;
    border-top: 400px solid #FFF;
}
```

Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0y7n9kLf/1/). (updated link for some housekeeping)